# Proving that a number is non-negative?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

The numbers $a$,$b$ and $c$ are real.
 Prove that at least one of the three numbers 
$$(a+b+c)^2 -9bc \hspace{1cm} (a+b+c)^2 -9ca \hspace{1cm} (a+b+c)^2-9ab$$
is non-negative.

Any hints would be appreciated too.

Comment: Have you considered adding them up and seeing if they are a square ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

If all three numbers are negative, then:

$$ab > \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2 \hspace{1cm} ac > \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2 \hspace{1cm} bc > \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2 \hspace{1cm}$$

Therefore, if we multiply the three inequalities:

$$a^2b^2c^2 > \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^6$$

Or equivalently:

$$\left(\sqrt[3]{abc}\right)^6 > \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^6$$

Do you know any inequality you can use here do disprove this?

Comment: @Sudhanshu Look for the Arithmetic-Geometric Median Inequality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

It says that:

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$$

Comment: Oh, how can I forget that...Thanks btw.

Comment: But since we assume these numbers to be negative how can we apply A.M > G.M ?

Comment: If we assume those three numbers are negative, then they contradict the "AM>GM" inequality wich we know to be true. Therefore our assumption was incorrect, i.e. at least one of those numbers was not negative. This sort of proof is called "proof by contradiction" or "reductio ad absurdum". You start with a hypothesis and you end up in a contradiction, wich means that the hypothesis was false.

Comment: But I think the A.M > G.M rule is applicable only for positive numbers

Comment: Note that the RHS of the original inequalities are squares, therefore, the LHS must be non-negative. Wich is only possible if $a,b,c$ are all negative or all positive (if $a,b,c$ are all negative then $AM-GM$ tells us that the three original inequalities can be true simultaneously, so perhaps there's a condition missing?)

Comment: I think I got it right, Please correct me if I am wrong. Since we have to prove that those expressions are positive, (which we assumed to be negative), So , a,b,c Can be positive and thus we could apply the AM > GM rule

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum [(a+b+c)^2-9bc]=3\sum[a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca]=\frac32\sum (a-b)^2\ge0$$

If each $(a+b+c)^2-3bc<0,$  $$\sum [(a+b+c)^2-3bc]<0$$

Comment: @Sudhanshu, How about this?

Comment: Could you explain how you took 3 as common out of that Sum sign?

Comment: You can also observe that $\sum[a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca]\ge0$ is just Cauchy -Schwarz.

Comment: @Macavity, Thanks for your observation